# Positive lookbehind or non-capturing group in POSIX ERE (Extended Regular Expressions)

Tags: regex, awk, capturing-group, regex-lookarounds

In a CSV file there are lines similar to this one:

```
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/30342373" width="640" height="364" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I want to extract `30342373` from these lines, which is between `vimeo.com/video/` and `"`. I tried the following regex in `mawk`:

```
vimeo\.com\/video\/[^"]*
```

Which is capturing: `vimeo.com/video/30342373`

If I know right, `mawk` only supporting POSIX ERE syntax, which is similar to `egrep`.

How can I capture only the unique video id part from the lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk '{gsub(/.*vimeo.com\/video\/|".*/,"")}1' file
30342373
```

Answer (score 1):

It is easier with `sed`:

```
str='<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/30342373" width="640" height="364" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>'

sed 's~.*\.vimeo\.com/video/~~; s~" .*~~' <<< "$str"

30342373
```

This `sed` first strip everything from start to `vimeo.com/video/` and then strips everything from `"` to end, thus leaving us with just the unique id.